# PropertyChange always return NULL in UWP?

Tags: uwp, inotifypropertychanged

I am making an UWP store application for Windows 10. I using an API and I am connecting to a server.

I just need to bind the textbox an error message on invalid login. But on calling the method OnPropertyChanged eventHandler always return the value null?

```
public LoginPasswordView()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    var vm = new LoginPasswordViewModel(new NavigationService(), new LoginService());
    this.DataContext = vm;      
}
```

viewmodel.cs

```
public class LoginPasswordViewModel : MainViewBaseModel
{
    private string password;
    private string errorMessage="We need this info to countinue";

    public LoginPasswordViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, ILoginService loginService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        _loginService = loginService;
    }

    private INavigationService _navigationService { get; set; }
    private ILoginService _loginService { get; set; }

    public string Errormessage
    {
        get
        {
            return errorMessage;
        }
        set
        {
            errorMessage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Errormessage");
        }
    }
}

public class MainViewBaseModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (eventHandler != null)
            eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));           
    }
}
```

The XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Errormessage,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="250,25,0,0" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Segoe Pro" Foreground="Red"/>
```

Comment: Please show your binding expression in XAML.

Comment: <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Errormessage,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="250,25,0,0" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Segoe Pro" Foreground="Red"/>

Comment: Hi, when adding information to the question, please edit it and add it there.  This ensures users do not have to read through the comments to get a full picture of the problem you are facing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: @GhostCat
Thank you.That's what i mean

Comment: It is something to do with the binding in XAML. Could you show all the XAML code of the LoginPasswordView class?

Answer (score 0):

use **x:Bind** instead of **Binding** syntax, x:Bind is much more flexible and performant also you have less chance of errors.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension

and because you are using **INotifyPropertyChanged** you should used **Mode="OneWay"** with **x:Bind** further details can bee seen in the link provided above.

Answer (score 0):

If your custom class implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and call the `OnPropertyChanged` handler in property's `set`, it will notify the UI, typically binding clients, that a property value has changed.

So, your issue actually is how you change the property's value, but I did not see where you change the `Errormessage`'s value in your above code.

I made a simple code sample for your reference according to your code.

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Password,Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Errormessage,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="250,25,0,0" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Segoe Pro" Foreground="Red"/>
</StackPanel>
```

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        var vm = new LoginPasswordViewModel();
        this.DataContext = vm;
    }
}

public class LoginPasswordViewModel : MainViewBaseModel
{
    private string password;
    private string errorMessage = "We need this info to countinue";

    public LoginPasswordViewModel()
    {

    }

    public string Password
    {
        get { return password; }
        set
        {
            password = value;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password.Trim()))
            {
                Errormessage = "Password cannot be null or empty!";
            }
            else
            {
                Errormessage = string.Empty;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("Password");
        }
    }


    public string Errormessage
    {
        get
        {
            return errorMessage;
        }
        set
        {
            errorMessage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Errormessage");
        }
    }
}

public class MainViewBaseModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (eventHandler != null)
            eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```